# Declare an Abstract class in php

Tags: php, abstract

I have 2 classes - A and B 
both should use config file from .ini or .php . 
and both have method call post  to get smth from diffrent api 
what is the best way to design it ?

Do I need to use abstact an put the config in his constructor . ?
I will be able to get the config with just call $this->config?

for example:

```
abstract class parent
{
  constructor()
   {
   $this->config = "get file";
}
}

class a extends parent {
   ...
   how to use $this->conifg ? 

}
```

thx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a function inside your parent class, that returns you your config:

```
abstract class parent
{

   private config;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->config = "get file";
   }

   public function getConfig(){
      return $this->config;
   }

}

class a extends parent
{

   private config;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->config = parent::getConfig();
   }

}
```